# Setting value of form fields using JQuery - only works if not edited by user?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input box where values are separated by commas. Since some of these values can be quite large, I thought I would use a bit of JQuery to split them in modal dialog so the user can see the list at a glance.

However, the JQuery code only works until the user edits one the fields, after which any attempts to use JQuery .val() or .attr('value','data') has no effect.

My code is below for anyone interested:

http://pastebin.com/8jt93yhr

The buttons work fine until you start changing the fields, then afterwards nothing changes.

Comment: Isn't that because they change the value so you don't have access to them anymore?  Why not just store the values somewhere else other than that input element?

Comment: solution partially dependent on how you expect user to interact with this. Which takes precedence  input,textarea or both? Perhaps would be easier for user to work within a table which would be sortable, editiable and filterable. Can map values to array easily from table

Comment: Normally there are only a few items, so it makes more sense to just display them inline as a comma seperated list. I thought a textarea would allow the user to see the list easier if they had a large amount of items, but I think a table is a better solution, as you point out. Didn't want to code it, but it seems there are some decent editable tables out there for jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.val()` to get/set the contents of the `textarea` as well..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Y4YkL/1/

Comment: Using 'val' seems to work well, which is strange, as I've always used things like innerHTML when working directly (without JQuery).